# How to catch or skip error lines in Datastage when inserting lines in ODBC

Tags: insert, db2, odbc, datastage

I'am using Datastage 11.7 , I want to insert lines my odbc table , however while inserting I want to skip or catch the line that goes down while inserting all the lines in my odbc , all of that so my flow won't go and will continue inserting even if there is an error i need to catch that line or skip it , after that will i need to retrieve that line in order to send it to the ETL support team .
Example :
`Dataset ( 10 lines ) -> copy stage -> ODBC`
while inserting the 10 lines , 1 of them may have a en error so in this case i want to get that line out of the insertion and let the 9 rest line continue their work .
I tried using the reject mode of the ODBC but it's not working even with that process all the flow go down , last example a line was already there so when i tried to insert the 10 lines it went donw cause of that and only line . how can I solve this problem please ? thank you in advance

Comment: Using a Reject link is the way to go - I have no idea what you mean with "it went down" - post the settings used in the Output Tab of your ODBC Connector or describe the error shown.

Comment: Does the reject link handles the error of duplicated value , like when i try to insert a line that is already there , can the reject link put it in a file ? if yes how can i configure it

Comment: Yes it can handle or better catch duplicatesso you will know which key is already in the database. You could use a Transformer and a Sequential File for the Reject link. Check all 4 checkboxes for the reject.

Comment: ok thank you @MichaelTiefenbacher but what's the purpose of the transformer that comes out from the odbc to the reject line ?